# Query multiple JSON tables inside javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

[Codepen with working example.](http://codepen.io/losephjambert/pen/dXzpgN?editors=0010)

I'm still new to javascript, so I could be going about this the wrong way. If you can suggest a better way for me to do this, I would greatly appreciate it; always love to learn a new, better way!

Here goes:

I use the array **iD** to generate the URL's of the 10 JSON tables I'm pulling data from.

```
var set = $('.set');

var iD = [
  "od6",
  "o9mpc0w",
  "ol96q2e",
  "olqcdyz",
  "ojfsm09",
  "oijguh3",
  "obmuic4",
  "oup920g",
  "ohwlz67",
  "omk1ruv"
];

function photoSet(){

  var idLength = iD.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < idLength; i++) {
```

Once I iterate through the array, I use an ajax call to query each one.

```
    $.ajax({
      url:'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1TBjwQNVRMNzuyZRxr9yX-fUKWw6gpUX69o9PQc79COs/' + iD[i] + '/public/values?alt=json',
      async: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: photos});
```

After they're queried, I retrieve the data from the cells of each JSON table and use it as an image src to insert into the document.

```
    function photos(results){
      for(var a = 1; a <= 1; a++) {
        var imageEntry = results.feed.entry[a].content.$t;
        set.append('<li class="image"><img src="'+ imageEntry +'"/></li>');
        console.log(imageEntry);
      }
    } 
  }
}

photoSet();
```

Here's the issue: **I need to have the resulting images in the same order as the array *iD***

Every time the page loads, the images are displayed in a different order. I know it's doing this because the queries are coming in at slightly different times, thus resulting in a different order every page load.

Does it have something to do with storing the ajax calls in variables, then grabbing them one at a time? Do I need another callback? As the nesting gets more complex, I get more confused :/

I've been searching high and low for how to do this, but just can't seem to figure it out. It seems with each new discovery I make, a new problem arises. Such is the nature of code, I suppose. Thank you all for your help :)

Also, [I saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380714/how-to-retrieve-multiple-json-objects-with-a-for-loop-in-javascript), but am having trouble figuring out how to apply its answer to my code. If I do, I'll remove this question promptly.

Comment: Would you be happy with getting the img src'es back in order all at the same time? As opposed to showing them as them coming in

Comment: I would! As a side note, when I change async to false and dataType to json, they come in at the correct order. Is that reliable? I don't actually understand why that works. I amended the codepen to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  `id` to the building of the `li`-

`set.append('<li class="image" id="sequnce"><img src="'+ imageEntry +'"/></li>');`

e.g

```
<li class="image" id="1"><img src="d.gif"/></li>
<li class="image" id="4"><img src="d.gif"/></li>
<li class="image" id="3"><img src="d.gif"/></li>
```

And after you finish to retrieve all the data from the Json you can sort the `li`.
You can use this link [How to sort LI's based on their ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630397/how-to-sort-lis-based-on-their-id)

Answer (score 0):

In our `iD` `for` loop we change the ajax to something like this...

```
var allResults = {}, successCount = 0;
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1TBjwQNVRMNzuyZRxr9yX-fUKWw6gpUX69o9PQc79COs/' + iD[i] + '/public/values?alt=json',
  async: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function( results ) {
    successCount++;
    allResults[ iD[i] ] = photos( results );
    if ( successCount == iD.length ) {
      //All data received...
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < idLength; i2++) {
        set.append( allResults[ iD[i2] ] )
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Now instead of calling photos directly we call a anonymous (unnamed) function which keeps a track of successful ajax request count and stores the images HTML in new object `allResults` with key matching `iD` array. When success count is equal `iD.length` we know all requests have been made and al HTML is saved in `allResults` object. We then run a `for` loop like we did for `ajax` requests and populate data in sequence of `iD` array.

The `photos` function, doesn't immediately `append` html into `set` now but returns all data, it should look like this...

```
function photos(results){
  returnString = '';
  for(var a = 1; a <= 1; a++) {
    var imageEntry = results.feed.entry[a].content.$t;
    returnString += '<li class="image"><img src="'+ imageEntry +'"/></li>';
    console.log(imageEntry);
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Oh, this looks intriguing. Thanks for the quick feedback. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: `var allResults = {}, successCount = 0;` should lie outside the loop ;-)

Comment: Hey @JosephLambert How did it go?

Comment: Apologies @wpdevelopment.me for the late response! I had to move over to another part of the project because of a deadline. I'll be returning to this tonight or tomorrow :)